# Javascript button to apply css filter on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-filters

I want to create a button that when clicked executes some javascript code to
change the img's css to `filter:sepia(100%);`

This is what I've got, the button is clickable but doesn't apply the filter…

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>
</head> 
<body>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="yeah"/>
    <button onclick="sep()" id="button"></button>

    <script>
        button.onclick=sep(){document.getElementsByTagName("img").style.filter="sepia(100%)"};
    </script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of DOM objects, you either need to iterate through them or access your image another way.  I'd suggest giving it an id and accessing it through `getElementById`.

Comment: either `button.onclick = function(){...}` or `onclick="sep()"` `function sep(){...}`

Comment: @user3507600 I changed it to `getElementById("hills")` and added an `id="hills"` to the img but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh, you also need to reference your button this way. `getElementById("button").onclick ...`

Answer (score 0):

with jquery a solution could be

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("img").addClass("sepia");
});
```

and class

```
.sepia{ -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
-webkit-filter: sepia(100%); -moz-filter: sepia(100%);
-ms-filter: sepia(100%); -o-filter: sepia(100%);
filter: sepia(100%);
filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
zoom:1;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MYJLb/)